# How to determine if my RegExp syntax is correct?

Tags: regex, syntax

I have the below syntax RegExp, however it's not pulling in the correct number, but on just the first app which is only 4 statuses it's pulling in the right number.

I'm not sure if the code is correct, how can I check if it is?

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st appointment - agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment - Email – Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment - F2F – Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment - Provisional – Call back.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment - Provisional – Cancelled.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment - Telephone – Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment Cancelled - Pre Appt – Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment Cancelled At Office – Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment - No Show - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment - Not Held - Disabled.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment Held - 2nd Appt Booked - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment Held - DNQ - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment Held - ERQ Completed - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment Held - Not Proceeding - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appointment Held - On Review - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*1st Appt Held - Over 6 Months.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*2nd Appointment - Disabled.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*2nd Appointment Cancelled - Pre Appt - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*2nd Appointment Held - Not Proceeding - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*2nd Appointment Held - On Review - Adviser.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Busy - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Call back - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*DNQ - Age - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*DNQ - Investments - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*DNQ - LTV - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*DNQ – Other – Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*DNQ - Property Type - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Does Not Qualify - Disabled.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Duplicate – Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Future Contact – Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not Interested - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not made enquiry - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Uncontactable.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Wanted A Face to Face - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Wanted Information - Agent.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*RIO Wanted.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Remortgage Wanted.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*RS Pension Referral.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not Interested - Alt funding.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not interested - Cant raise funds.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not Interested – Competitor.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not Interested - Didnt want a call.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not interested - Down sizing.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not Interested - Not made inquiry.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not Interested - Wanted a quote.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not Interested - Wanted rates.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Not Interested – Hang Up.*')
THEN 1
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Lead Status, '.*Existing Customer Query.*')
THEN 1
else 0
end
```

Comment: That's a lot to digest, but it looks like you could condense a lot of these alternations inside groupings and return a boolean value (true/false) which you can convert in a 1 or 0, essentially removing all these 'WHEN' - 'THEN' clauses.

Comment: Hi, Ive never used boolean is there anywhere i can have a look at what i need to do somewhere?

Comment: Could you add into this some examples of text that ought match but does not?

Comment: I suspect this is SQL - what database are you using? Is it MySQL?

Comment: You may find that the `.*` devices are redundant - by default a regular expression will match a string if it matches in the middle - you only need to put in additional matchers if you are using start/end anchors.